# Curious polynomial factorization identity

Tags: combinatorics, factoring

Let $j \in {\mathbb N}$ and $q \in {\mathbb N}$ be positive integers and let $n$ be a parameter. Define:
\begin{equation}
Q_j:=3 \left\lfloor \frac{j-2}{2}\right\rfloor +2 \left\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2}\right\rfloor +4
\end{equation}

Then the following identity holds:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{1}{\left(-j+n+Q_j\right)^{1\cdot 1_{j \bmod 2=0} + 2 \cdot 1_{j \bmod 2=1}}}\\
&&\left(\right.\\
&&\left.
\frac{(5 j+2 q-3)^{(3)}}{Q_j+q}
\right.\\
&&\left.
\frac{6 (5 j+2 q-1)^2 }{Q_j+q+1}\cdot (-j+n-q)^{(1)}+\right.\\
&&\left.12 \frac{(5 j+2 q) }{Q_j+q+2} \cdot (-j+n-q-1)^{(2)} +\right.\\
&&\left.
\frac{8 }{Q_j+q+3} \cdot (-j+n-q-2)^{(3)}\right.\\
&&\left.
\right)=\\
&&  
\begin{array}{r}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!-4 (15 j+4 q-4)+8 Q_j+\frac{6 \left(25 j^2+20 j q-10 j+4 q^2-4 q+1\right)}{Q_j+q+1}+
 \left(\frac{60 j+24 q}{Q_j+q+2}-8\right) \cdot (-j+n-q)+
\frac{8 }{Q_j+q+3} \cdot (-j+n-q-1)^{(2)} & \mbox{if $j$ is even} \\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\frac{60 j+24 q}{Q_j+q+2}-16+\frac{8 }{Q_j+q+3}\cdot (-j+n-q) & \mbox{if $j$ is odd}
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
Note that the left hand side of the identity above is a rational function in $n$ and the right hand side is a polynomial in $n$. As such the identity states that the numerator of the left hand side is always divisible by the denominator whatever values for $j$ and $q$ we choose. We discovered this identity by inserting random values for $j$ and $q$ into the lhs and then noticing that the result is always a polynomial (meaning no fraction) in $n$.

```
In[360]:= Clear[Q]; 
Q[j_] := 4 + 3 Floor[1/2 (-2 + j)] + 2 Floor[1/2 (-1 + j)];
j = RandomInteger[{0, 50}];
q = RandomInteger[{0, 50}]; n =.;
eX = 1/Pochhammer[n - j + Q[j] + 1, 
     If[Mod[j, 2] == 0, 1, 
      2]] (Pochhammer[2 q + 5 j - 3, 3] 1/(q + Q[j]) (1) +
      6 (-1 + 5 j + 2 q)^2 1/(1 + q + Q[j]) (n + -j - q - 0) +
      (60 j + 24 q) 1/(2 + q + Q[j]) (n + -j - q - 1) (n - j - q) +
      8 1/(
       3 + q + Q[j]) (n + -j - q - 2) (n - j - q - 1) (n - j - 
         q)) - (If[
     Mod[j, 2] == 
      0, (-4 (-4 + 15 j + 4 q) + 8 Q[j] + (
        6 (1 - 10 j + 25 j^2 - 4 q + 20 j q + 4 q^2))/(
        1 + q + Q[j])) + (-8 + (60 j + 24 q)/(2 + q + Q[j])) (n - j - 
         q) +  8/(3 + q + Q[j]) (n - j - q) (n - j - q - 1), -16 + (
      60 j + 24 q)/(2 + q + Q[j]) + 8/(3 + q + Q[j]) (n - j - q)]);
Simplify[eX]

Out[364]= 0
```

How would you go about proving this identity? Is there any combinatorial interpretation of this result ?

Comment: What is the meaning of the last "+"  before the closing parenthesis in the  "lhs"?

Comment: No meaning. I was formatting the equation by hand , reshuffling the terms for better visibility and a plus went astray.

Comment: Please format the MathJax by hand: both the source and the rendered output are currently a complete mess, and I suspect that there is a missing $+$ and possibly more errors. Not to mention the inconsistent use of $Q_j$ vs $Q(j)$, which I assume are meant to be the same.

Comment: @ Peter Taylor There were no errors in the original expression only a stray plus sign . But yes you are right there is nothing mysterious about this identity . Writing $Q_j$ explicitely as you did it below and then applying FullSimplify to the lhs simplifies the fraction and produces a polynomial as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Using *Mathematica* for odd and even $j$ separately it is possible to reduce the expression to the following more readable form:
$$
\begin{cases}
4\left(\frac{(3j+2n+2)(3 j+2 n+4)}{5 j+2 q+4}-\frac{6(3j+2n+2)}{5 j+2 q+2}+\frac{3}{5 j+2 q}\right),& j\bmod2=0;\\
8\left(\frac{3j+2n+3}{5 j+2 q+3}-\frac{3}{5 j+2 q+1}\right),& j\bmod2=1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I am sorry but the right hand side is a polynomial in $n$ whose order is two if $j$ is even and is one if $j$ is odd. Your expression is has always order three.

Comment: @Przemo Sorry for the error. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $$Q_j = 3 \left\lfloor \frac{j-2}{2}\right\rfloor +2 \left\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2}\right\rfloor +4 =
%3 floor(j/2 - 1) +2 floor(j/2 - 1/2) +4 =
\begin{cases}
\frac52j - 1 & \textrm{ if $j$ is even} \\
\frac52j - \frac32 & \textrm{ if $j$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Then separate into two identities, one for even $j$ and one for odd $j$. The algebra is ugly but algorithmic, so you can ask Mathematica to simplify it.